# Scraping value from this output

Tags: python, json, search, scrape

Good evening,

I want to scrape a "value" from this output:

```
{
  "checkout":
  {
    "completed_at": null,
    "created_at": "2020-02-27T00:32:40+01:00",
    "currency":"EUR",
    "presentment_currency":"EUR",
    "customer_id":2929596792912,
    "customer_locale":"de"
    ...
```

and so on....

My attempt:

```
import json
Json = json.loads(info.text)
currency= Json1.get("currency")
print(currency
```

But I just get `None` when I print the answer

Comment: Please check your example code. You are loading the json into a variable called `Json` and then calling `get` on a variable called `Json1`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have parsed the input using the `json` library you have a python dictionary.

The reason `get("currency")` returns `None` is because the key `currency` does not exist at the top level of your dictionary.

If you try

```
currency = Json.get("checkout").get("currency")
```

you should get the value `EUR`

Comment: Works. Thank you!